# Multi-Realm authentication (Forms + Custom authenticator)

Tags: java, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

We're in the process of building a Worklight application which has a 2 step authentication process.

**Step 1: Forms Authentication**

We're using the out of the box WASLTPARealm which authenticates us against a custom JAAS module in WebSphere and returns an LTPA token. This works as expected.

**Step 2: Custom Authenticator** 
The second step is a custom Authenticator and Login Module which:

- Reads the LTPA cookie that were set in Step 1
- Makes a POST request to another application with the LTPA cookie (these 2 apps are trusted via Single Sign-On)
- The POST request returns a response with additional session cookies
- The user is authenticated

The issue is that the Custom Authenticator doesn't fire when using the client code provided in the documentation. Basically

**The customAuthenticator is created via the usual**

```
var customAuthenticator = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("MyCustomRealm");
```

**Then further down in the client code**

```
var reqURL = '/my_custom_auth_request_url';
var options = {};
options.parameters = {};
options.headers = {};
customAuthenticator.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, customAuthenticator.submitLoginFormCallback);
```

**Results in a 404**

```
[27/05/13 10:35:07:616 NZST] 00000326 WebSphereForm I com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator processRequest FWLSE0055I: Not recognized.
[27/05/13 10:35:07:616 NZST] 00000326 Authenticatio E com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter doFilter FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
```

Which happens because the request gets picked up by the WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator instead of our Custom Authenticator.

We're writing the request URL to the logs inside the custom authenticator via

```
public AuthenticationResult processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, boolean isAccessToProtectedResource) throws IOException,   ServletException {
        logger.info("Request URL is: " + request.getRequestURI());
```

But that line never gets hit.

Can 2 authenticators work side by side? The behaviour I'm seeing is that

```
var wlFormsAuthenticator = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("WASLTPARealm");
```

and

```
var customAuthenticator = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("MyCustomRealm");
```

seem to get mixed up. I thought that calling `submitLoginForm` on the customAuthenticator should not be getting picked up by the WebSphereForms authenticator and instead should go to our custom one.

Can you please clarify the expected behaviour and a potential Workaround?

**Also, what DOES work is calling**

```
WL.Client.login("MyCustomRealm", {
    onSuccess: function() {

    },
    onFailure: function() {

    }
});
```

In this case, the Java code gets hit and we successfully authenticate **BUT**, the URL is

```
http://localhosT:9080/worklight/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/login
```

Rather than `my_custom_auth_request_url` which means we can't filter out the requests in our Java code.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a mix of terminology in your description. 
Authenticator is server side entity. Custom Authenticator is implemented in Java.
Challenge handler is a client side entity. It is implemented in JavaScript.

From your description I'm guessing that you're trying to submit login form for custom authenticator before actually trying to get some resource from WL server. The problem is that instance of custom authenticator is only created once you try to access protected resource. Authenticator will refuse to receive credentials (or more generally - it will not really exist) unless you trigger authentication first. So your approach is correct, you might call WL.Client.login("realm") to trigger authentication process first. Other options are:

1. protect application environment using security test and set connectOnStartup:true
2. protect application environment using security test, set connectOnStartup:false and use WL.Client.connect() API.

Comment: Excuse the confusion with the naming of the variables. They should be called `wlFormsChallengeHandler` and `customChallengeHandler`. I do understand the concept and the distinction between the client-side and server-side entities. As I mentioned I am **already** using the `WL.Client.login()` method but the URL that is being used is not my custom URL specified in my *client-side* code but rather it's `baseurl/login' thus filtering cannot be performed in the **Java** code.

Comment: Can you explain exactly the process you would use for a combination of a Forms Authenticator and a Custom Authenticator solution especially in the client side code?

Comment: /my_custom_auth_request_url is only used to send credentials. WL.Client.login("realm") should make request to /login API, this is OK. What happens when you make WL.Client.login(..) request? What do you get in response?